# JavaScript assignment in return statement

Tags: javascript, return, variable-assignment

I've come across a piece of JS code much like this:

```
let myFn = function(param) {
    if (param > 5)
        return param = 10; // <-- why?
    return param;
}
```

This code works, which I wouldn't assume if someone asked. But, I see no difference between just returning a value in a regular way:

```
let p1 = 34;
let p2 = 5;

myFn(p1); // returns 10
myFn(p2); // returns 5
console.log(p1); // 34
console.log(p2); // 5
```

So, the question is – is there a reason for this at all?

Comment: There's no reason for that. The author of the code may have been confused, or that may be a remnant of different code that has since been removed.

Comment: The code works because the expression `param = 10` results in `10`. Other than that, it isn't doing much. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Return_value_and_chaining

Comment: Shorter version is using a ternary: `let myFn = param => param > 5 ? 10 : param;`

Comment: I've seen people do this kind of thing, I've always personally discouraged it as overly obtuse but it will work and it makes some people feel clever <shrug>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is no functional reason to do this.

---

Since the result of `param = 10`, is indeed `10`, there's no
*functional* difference between;

```
return param = 10;
return 10;
```

While [benchmarking the code](https://jsben.ch/AYtcq), returning the assingment slows down the code; **100%** vs **99.46%**.

---

The only reason I could imagine a developer to choose this option, is to let further developers know that the function is returning a new value of `param`.

So instead of looking for the function call, the developer could see that the function is overriding the `param` variable with the new `10` value.

Comment: This is just an opinion

Comment: Benchmarking a variable assignment really is the height of [premature optimisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)